# How can I get the class (custom) of cell selected in UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

Usually I get my selected cell this way:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)table didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*) [table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

But in the code I'm working with, I may have many kind of cells in my table view. How can I get the class of my selected cell (if it's for example `CustomCell` or `CustomCell2`) ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can check the type of cell returned

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if ([cell isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]]) {
     //do specific code
}else if([cell isKindOfClass:[CustomCell2 class]]){
    //Another custom cell
}else{
    //General cell
}
```

Comment: @reggie for _Swift_ 3 I use **`is`** to replace `isKindOfClass`. For example `if (cell is MyCustomTableViewCell) { return true } else {return false}`

Answer (score 9):

**SWIFT 4**

Just in case, if someone needed it. Get the `instance of selected cell and then check it for required tableViewCell type.`

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let cell = myCustomCell.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
            else
        {
            return
        }

/** MyCustomCell is your tableViewCell class for which you want to check. **/

    if cell.isKind(of: MyCustomCell.self) 
        {
           /** Do your stuff here **/
        }
}
```